# pip is showing error after downloading OPENSSL

Tags: python, ubuntu, openssl, python-2.x, ubuntu-18.04

pip command is showing error.
i downloaded libraries from https://github.com/rajpaul/igotoeurope/blob/master/requirements.txt then it started showing error in pip. i tried uninstalling the pip command and reinstalling the same still it didn't work.

Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/**init**.py", line 33, in vendored
            **import**(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.cachecontrol'

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    vendored("cachecontrol")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/wrapper.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "/home/aaroosh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/home/aaroosh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 11, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/home/aaroosh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/home/aaroosh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
AttributeError: module '_cffi_backend' has no attribute '_init_cffi_1_0_external_module'
```

Comment: It is solved i removed OPEN SSL library and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by removing OPENSSL library.